# Including page into another using twig and symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony, highcharts, twig

I have a chart page and i want to include it into my base page when i open my base page it show me this `Variable "chart" does not exist` you can see My chart page :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/4.1.8/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/4.1.8/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">{{ chart(chart) }}</script>

<div id="barchart" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

in my base page i write this

```
{% include 'companyevents/charts.html.twig'%}
```

Comment: How are you passing the `chart` variable to your view?

Comment: actually i'm asking how i can  passed the chart variable ?

Comment: Watch the answer of Aurelia

Answer (score 0):

In your Symfony Controller:

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/MyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function renderMyPage()
    {
        $chart = #code ...
        $this->render('@App/path/to/template.html.twig', array(
            'chart' => $chart
        ));
    }
}
```

This will pass your chart variable to the base template that includes your chart template.

Include your relevant JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src={{asset('path/to/javascript.js')}}></script>
```

If you have a JavaScript function that requires the chart variable as a parameter you can now call use it:

Example:

```
<button id ='exampleUsage' onclick='myFunction({{ chart }})'>Button</button>
```

Inside your chart template you will be able to call this as long as it is passed to the base template your chart template is being included in.

```
<div id="barchart" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">{% include 'companyevents/charts.html.twig'%}</div>
```

Comment: what you mean with <script type='text/javascript' src={{asset('path/to/javascript.js')}}></script>

Comment: but where i will put this line <button id ='exampleUsage' onclick='myFunction({{ chart }})'>Button</button>

Comment: It's just an example of how to call the function via a button click. You have to decide how you need the function to be called whether it be via user action or a specific event.

Answer (score -1):

```
{# template.html will have access to the variables from the current context and the additional ones provided #}
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

Bar should exist in current context or passed using 'with'

https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/include.html

You set 'chart' in base template?

Comment: If the the variable `chart` was passed towards the base template than it is known inside the include whether you pass it explicit or not. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/a301am)

Comment: {% include 'companyevents/charts.html.twig', { 'chart': chart } %}
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" ("end of statement block" expected). so how i can passed it ?